# python del a element in for loop

Tags: python, list, enumerate

For loop with enumerate doesn't throw index out of range error while a an element is deleted inside loop?

```
L = [1, 4, 8, 5]
try:
  for i,item in enumerate(L): 
    print("Value of {} is {}".format(i, item))
    del L[i]
except IndexError as e:
    print("Index error: {err}.".format(err=e))
```

Output:

```
Value of 0 is 1
Value of 1 is 8
```

While this code causes the error

```
L = [1, 4, 8, 5]
try:
    for i in range(len(L)):
        print("Item:", L[i])
        del(L[i])
except IndexError as e:
    print("Error:", e)
```

Output:

```
Item: 1 
Item: 8
Error: list index out of range
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this isn't a duplicate (of that one at least). OP knows that there's a problem. OP just wants to know the difference of behaviour between the two.

Comment: I'd be surprised if we didn't have a proper duplicate somewhere, though -- variants on the question get asked a lot.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Reopened, though I'm pretty sure the question I linked would help the OP, and virtually everyone else who gets here in the future.

Comment: @SvenMarnach if you check my answer, you'll see that I linked it as well :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy there are questions asking what happens when removing while iterating. This one is (just slightly) different because it compares the behaviour of a dummy `for` loop using `range` with a `for` loop using an iterator. I found that different enough to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Both codes are *wrong* (see [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)), but the symptoms are different in both cases.

In the first case, you're *iterating* on `L`. Shortening `L` makes iteration end faster (notice that some items are skipped, because shortening the list confuses the internal iterator, which raises a `StopIteration`, which stops the `for` loop)

You could create some equivalent code of the first case using a `while` loop:

```
L = [1, 4, 8, 5]
try:
    i = 0
    while i < len(L):
        print("Item:", L[i])
        del(L[i])
        i += 1
except IndexError as e:
    print("Error:", e)
```

or emulating the fact that `for` loop catches the `StopIteration` exception raised by `next` on the `enumerate` iterator:

```
e = enumerate(L)
while True:
try:
   i,item = next(e)
   print("Value of {} is {}".format(i, item))
   del L[i]
except StopIteration:
    break
```

you get the same result, because `len(L)` is evaluated at each iteration, so the index *cannot* get out of bounds (but the result isn't very useful either)

In the second case, you've computed `range(len(L))` with the initial list size. So after a while, the index is out of range for the shortened list.

The first case doesn't crash, but the result is hard to understand, implementation defined, cannot be relied on. Don't do this.

Comment: Thanks Jean. I knew the first case is bad code. Just learning to understand it better. What does enumerate do so skipping items on delete end up in index error.

Comment: the `while` code I have added gives a good idea of what enumerate does. Well, it's not exactly like that (`enumerate` can work on a non-list iterable) but it looks very much like that.

Comment: Sorry to drag this further. I am just going mad :). From your statement : "Shortening L makes iteration end faster (notice that some items are skipped, because shortening the list confuses the internal iterator, which raises a StopIteration, which stops the for loop)". My question is simple, "Why exception StopIteration is not getting caught when this was iterated using for loop"

Comment: @Darshan For loops consume the `StopIteration` exception.  This exception is part of the iterator protocol and indicates the end of the iteration.  A for loop creates an iterator for the iterable you pass in and calls `next()` on that iterator until `StopException` is raised, at which point the loop stops.

Answer (score 0):

In the second code with range, the interpreter actually expands your range loop so it will try to print(L[2]) while your list has only two value.